# How to end the previous function call on a new call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $( window ).on( "load", function() {
        myfunc();
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(this.id);
        this.id = setTimeout(myfunc, 200);
    });

    function myfunc(){
        $( "#myid" ).click(function() {alert('Hello');});
    }
</script>
</head><body>
<img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" id="myid">
</body></html>
```

Use the minimize and expand button in your browser. After first resize click on the image and you will see two alerts. After second resize you will see three alerts and so on. How to end the previous function call on a new call to see only alert from the last call of `myfunc()`? I need this style of resize detecting because I need to change some elements on the others right after resizing.

Comment: You're attaching a new handler every time the window is resized. There's no need, the one you've already attached (on load) will continue working. But if you *did* need to un-attach a handler, [the documentation tells you how to do that](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: Don't reattach the event handler on each resize. Just invoke the callback function.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, Right after resizing I need to replace some elements with the others without any other actions from the user. I'll try .off() to un-attach a handler.

Comment: @williamzo: Again: There's no need to detach and reattach the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your window gets resized, you call your `myfunc` function, which registers the same callback anonymous function that shows the alert over and over.

Instead, give the function that shows the `alert` a name, register click function that calls a separately named function that shows the `alert` just once and call it as needed:

```js
function showAlert(){
  alert('Hello');
}

$(window).on("load", function(){
  // Separate the code that actually produces the alert
  // so it can be called as needed.
  $("#myid").on("click", showAlert);
  showAlert();
});

$(window).resize(timer);

function timer() {
  clearTimeout(this.id);
  this.id = setTimeout(showAlert, 200);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" id="myid">
```

Comment: Your code is very good but it doesn't really fit me, because I need to perform some operations right after resizing without any click from the user. For example, to replace one type of arrows on another type if the window width < 400px, another type of arrows if 400 <= window width < 1000px, and another type of arrows if window width >= 1000px

Comment: @williamzo This code does exactly that. You would place that code in the `showAlert` function, which runs just after every resize.

Comment: @williamzo Here's a question though, what is the point of the timer? Why not just perform the actions needed in the `resize` event callback itself? Also, from your description, it sounds like none of this is necessary and instead, you should just be using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: I need the timer because $(window).resize(); will be triggered twice on resize start and resize end. I don't need it. CSS does not suits me, because on the page I have an image with a dynamic width and a div block which width depends on the image width. More than that the div block can be even truncated and it depends on the database. I must change it's width with JS. In your example initial loading will happen only after the click - $("#myid").on("click", showAlert); I'll play with your example. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example but I need to perform some actions right after page loading without user's click. on("click") should be inside showAlert() and in that case your example will trigger the same problems.

Comment: @williamzo No, inside the `.on("load", function`, just after the `$("#myid").on("click", showAlert);`, you would just add: `showAlert()`. This way you get the automatic behavior you need during load without re-registering the event handler over and over. I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: Maybe while posting my question I simplified my task, therefore it was quite difficult for me to rewrite my code with your logic. But I did this today and now I understand that your code is exactly what I needed. I didn't understand this at first and it seems that your experience here is very large and you understood me better than me. Thank you very much! Your code example is great and you helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the resize function will trigger multiple times, you can find out yourself by doing `console.log("Handler for .resize() called.");` inside the resize function, so you will understand what is going on, and why it's happening.

A simple fix that can solve this problem is by using `setInterval()` function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(window).on( "load", function() {
    myfunc();
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var loop = setInterval(myfunc, 30);
    clearInterval(loop);
  });
  function myfunc(){
    $("#myid").click(function(){
     alert('Hello');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/32054" id="myid">
```

Comment: Looks like a not very elegant solution because of the constantly working javascript code. But thank you for this option.

Comment: @williamzo, what do you mean with "constantly working javascript code"?

Comment: `var loop = setInterval(myfunc, 30);` - myfunc will run every 30 milliseconds.

Comment: No it will not, that's why there is a clearInterval() right after it.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp - The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds). The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Comment: "until clearInterval() is called" and that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I'll check your method better. Thanks.

Comment: Ok awesome, please mark as best answer if you wish.

Comment: Hmm any news? you didn't mark as best solutions. Did it not solve your problem?

Comment: I used an advice of Scott Marcus. You may find it above. It works as I needed for me that's why I marked it as the best answer. So I did not use your answer, which, perhaps, would also suit me.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it is possible.

Javascript generally doesn't work Asynchronously. While it can ask the browser to send data and pass a callback function, any callback tends to be exacuted only when everything else is done, like events.
I'd you want to end a functions execution you will need to
return from the function.

It is not possible to pop a function from the stack while there are new functions on top of it.